# Why the errors?

Tags: c, pointers, stack

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000
struct stack { 
    int st[MAX];
    int *top ; 
};  

int main() {  
  struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
  s->(*top) = -1;
  return 0;
}
```

I am writing a piece of code for stack implementation in C. This is a practice assignment. Why do I get the following compilation errors?

error: expected identifier
  s->(*top) = -1;

error: use of undeclared identifier 'top'
  s->(*top) = -1;

Comment: What do you think `s->(*top) = -1;` is doing?

Comment: From what I have learnt so far, this line tries to assign to value -1 to the pointer variable top by deferencing it? Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hint: first it tries to dereference something called 'top'. 'top' is unknown in this context.

Comment: Would this would be the correct way to write it ? *(s->top) = -1;

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer is how you *use* its value. You can't assign a value to a pointer by dereferencing it. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign -1 to the pointer: `s->top = -1;` (should  give a warning but will probably compile).

If you want to assign -1 to the int top is pointing at `*(s->top) = -1;` will compile but probably crash since top is not pointing anywhere valid yet.

```
int anInteger;
struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
s->top = &anInteger;
*(s->top) = -1;
/* anInteger should now have the value -1 */
/* beware scope - if you did this somewhere other than main
   anInteger may go out of scope */
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer for this, but based on the names of your variables, I think what you really want to do is this:

```
s->top = s->st;
```

This will mean that "top" is pointing to position 0 of the stack, you can insert at the top and then increment like so:

```
*(s->top) = INSERT_VALUE;
s->top++;
```

To pop:

```
REMOVE_VALUE = *(s->top);
s->top--;
```

Neither has any bound checks.  Given that you've declared top as a pointer, this is what I think you want to do.  You don't usually store empty pointers as -1, you store them as 0 (or NULL).  That being said, using an empty pointer in this case just doesn't make any sense.